# extract first three numbers from a string

Tags: python, regex

I have strings like

```
"ABCD_ABCD_6.2.15_3.2"
"ABCD_ABCD_12.22.15_4.323"
"ABCD_ABCD_2.33.15_3.223"
```

I want to extract following from above

```
"6.2.15"
"12.22.15"
"2.33.15"
```

I tried using indices of numbers but cant use them since they are variable. Only thing constant here is the length of the characters appearing in the beginning of each string.

Comment: Ignore the first x characters (since they're constant), then split the string at each period and take the first three elements.

Comment: Or `split` on the `_` and take the 3rd part if it's the only one you need

Comment: Based on your questions, what if the input is `ABC_DEF_1_2.34.56_7_8` or `ABC_DEF_1_2.34_56.7_8` what is the output? Since you state that `extract first 3 numbers from a string`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way would be this regex:

```
_(\d+.*?)_

import re
m = re.search('_(\\d+.*?)_', 'ABCD_ABCD_6.2.15_3.2')
m.group(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a ton of ways to do this. Try:

```
>>> "ABCD_ABCD_6.2.15_3.2".split("_")[2]
'6.2.15'
```